# How do I add a default value to a field in a RoR migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

How do I add a default value to an existing field in a RoR migration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this would do the trick

```
change_column :users, :active, :boolean, :default => 1
```

Use the same data type as when you created the column but add the default parameter.